# The method 'cancel' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, null, non-nullable

I have the following code:

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String? _token;
  DateTime? _expiryDate;
  String? _userId;
  Timer? _authTimer;

  String? get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    _token = null;
    _userId = null;
    _expiryDate = null;
    if (_authTimer != null) {
      _authTimer.cancel();
      _authTimer = null;
    }
    notifyListeners();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // prefs.remove('userData');
    prefs.clear();
  }
}
```

And the following errors:

> The method 'isAfter' can't be unconditionally invoked because the
> receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.')
> or adding a null check to the target ('!').
>
> The method 'cancel' can't be unconditionally invoked because the
> receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.')
> or adding a null check to the target ('!').

How can I fix this error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines of code to this:

```
        _expiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&

      _authTimer!.cancel();
```

The issue is that Dart knows that `_expiryDate` or `_authTimer` can be `null`. However, you assert by checking them both for not being `null` in your `if` statement that they cannot possibly be `null` at that point. Thus, you can add a `!`, which is a non-null assertion, basically saying 'I know this variable can have a value of `null`, but I'm sure that it can't be `null` at this point'.

Comment: Very nice yes. Thanks I was working on an ammulinium app and this really helped me. Very good teacher.